# how to display random image in splashscreen in android?

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

i'm creating an android application with, of course, a loading/splash screen everytime the application is opened. i've created a splash screen xml and class. but with only one image.

 what i want to happen is to load different images and random texts everytime the application is launched.

here's my code on my splashscreen.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/exit1" />
 
 </RelativeLayout>
```

and here's my code in splashscreen.java

```js
package travelph.project;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
 // Randomise a background
    int[] yourListOfImages= {R.drawable.about1, R.drawable.background1
      , R.drawable.bakya1, R.drawable.coconut1, R.drawable.exit1hdpi};

 private static final int TIME = 5 * 1000;// 5 seconds

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);    // Removes title bar
  this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);    // Removes notification bar
  setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
       Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
       int posOfImage = random.nextInt(yourListOfImages.length + 1);
       ImageView imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
       imageView.setBackgroundResource(yourListOfImages[posOfImage]);
       
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainMenu.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    SplashScreen.this.finish();

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);

   }
  }, TIME);
  
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
            } 
       }, TIME);

 }

 
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  this.finish();
  super.onBackPressed();
 }
}
```

code snippet would really be a big help. thank you.

Comment: as this code looks ok at first glance to someone that only occasional dabbles in android development, it would be helpful to describe what happens and where it breaks

Answer (score 0):

below piece of your code should be strictly in `onCreate` (below under `setContentView` for example and above new `Handler` creation), not inside `postDelayed` -> `run()`

```
Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
int posOfImage = random.nextInt(yourListOfImages.length + 1);
ImageView imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(yourListOfImages[posOfImage]);
```

you are setting image after `TIME` and immidaitelly after that you are calling intent to another activity and current is finishing

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(yourListOfImages[posOfImage]);
```

to

```
imageView.setImageResource(yourListOfImages[posOfImage]);
```